# Does this argument make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Question:

U = {$x \in R$ | sin(x) = 1/2 }. Is U a closed set, an open set or neither?

Answer:

U = {...,-11$\pi$/6, -7$\pi$/6, $\pi$/6, 5$\pi$/6, 13$\pi$/6, 17$\pi$/6,...}

Then U complement =...$\cup$ (-11$\pi$/6, -7$\pi$/6) $\cup$ (-7$\pi$/6, $\pi$/6) $\cup$ ($\pi$/6, $5\pi$/6) $\cup$ (5$\pi$/6, 13$\pi$/6) $\cup$ ...

So U complement is the arbitrary union of open sets, so U complement is open, hence U is closed.

Comment: Is this for a class? What you say is true, but I'm not sure I would accept it as on answer to, say, a homework problem. Depends on the level of the class.

Comment: It's a practice question for an exam.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly a closed set as the preimage under a continuous function of a closed set is closed.  It is not open, because it's a proper subset of a connected space.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is true (just replace $\cap$ by $\cup$).

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.